# how can I get the parent path base on an environment variable

Tags: shell

I have a environment variable admin_path=/home/myfolder/server. now I need to get the parent path base on the $admin_path in shell script. how can I get it easily? thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not entirely clear what you want, but I think you are looking for:

```
${admin_path%/*}
```

to get the value of `admin_path` with the trailing path component removed.